# angularjs select box values based on another select box

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu

My data structure is

```
$scope.selectedNotification = {};

$scope.metricTypes = [{"metric":"storage","units":["%","MB","GB","TB","PB"]},{"metric":"memory","units":["PB","EB","YB"]},{"metric":"vcores","units":["vcores"]}];
```

My HTML is

```
<select ng-model="selectedNotification.metricType" ng-options="metricType.metric as metricType.metric for metricType in metricTypes"></select>

<select ng-model="selectedNotification.unit" ng-options="unit for unit in (select as metricType.units for metricType in ( metricTypes | filter: {metric: selectedNotification.metricType }))"></select>
```

I want to show the values for units select box based on the metric type selected. I need help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-change` like below

```
<select ng-model="selectedNotification.metricType" ng-options="metricType as metricType.metric for metricType in metricTypes" ng-change="units = selectedNotification.metricType.units"></select>

<select ng-model="selectedNotification.unit" ng-options="unit for unit in units"></select>
```

Have changed `ng-options="metricType.metric as metricType.metric for metricType in metricTypes"` to `ng-options="metricType as metricType.metric for metricType in metricTypes"` to get full selected object and in `ng-change` used that `object` to assign to `units` as `selectedNotification.metricType.units`

Comment: The value for what is selected in metric select box comes from the database, so there is no user activity of changing the select box

Comment: @Jamesbond - Sorry, but I didn't understand your use case, 1. If no user activity then as per `$scope.selectedNotification = {};` is initialised to empty object, first select box will be empty only; 2. If you want select boxes to be pre-selected then you have option to initialise both in your controller

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. No user activity in case of displaying the values fetched from the database for the select boxes. The respective values list for metrics and units select boxes must be populated using metricTypes json and the values that are stored in the database must selected.

Comment: please check this http://jsfiddle.net/0m9wwjdf/1/ have added both options 1. given above, 2. if you getting values in controller from DB

Comment: Thank you for the jsfiddle! It worked after making a few changes